# What is the difference between std::enable_if and std::enable_if_t?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, enable-if

C++-14 introduced `std::enable_if_t`.

What is the difference between it and `std::enable_if`? Are there any advantages or differences in using `std::enable_if_t`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

std::enable_if_t is a type alias of the inner ::type of std::enable_if, it's syntactic sugar so you don't have to write

```
typename std::enable_if</* */>::type
```

Answer (score 3):

The `_t` aliases were introduced in c++14, the `_v` ones were added in c++17.

Anywhere you use `enable_if::type` you can use `enable_if_t` (as long as your compiler and standard library support c++14) instead they are equivalent.

Comment: Note that whilst the alias templates for traits were introduced in C++14, the _variable templates for traits_ were only added in C++17, even if variables templates themselves were available already in C++14 (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322070/4573247) for details).

Answer (score 2):

`std::enable_if_t` enables you to skip `typename` and `::type`. So `std::enable_if_t` is an alias of `std::enable_if</*    */>::type`.

So instead of typename `std::enable_if</*   */>::type`, you can write as `std::enable_if_t</*    */>`.

Answer (score 2):

#### C++14 (N3655): Alias Templates for Traits

C++14 integrated all but part 4 of

- [N3655: TransformationTraits Redux, v2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf)

written by well-renowned template metaprogramming guru *Walter E. Brown*<sup>✝</sup>.

> What is the difference between it [`std::enable_if_t`] and `std::enable_if`? Are there any advantages or differences in using `std::enable_if_t`?

The `_t` alias templates for accessing the underlying `type` of a metafunction, `typename metafunction-name<metafunction-argument(s)>::type`, **has not been added solely as syntactic sugar to language**, but also to lessen the burden on inexperienced (Brown: *"[...] inexpert"*) metaprogramming developers when facing compiler error messages whilst working with metafunctions. Quoting (the majority parts of) Section 2 (*Proposal*) of N3655 [**emphasis** mine]:

> Unfortunately, the above-described flexibility comes with a cost for
>   the most common use cases. In a template context, C++ requires that
>   each “metacall” to a metafunction bear syntactic overhead in the form
>   of an introductory `typename`keyword, as well as the suffixed
>   `::type`:
>
> ```
> typename metafunction-name<metafunction-argument(s)>::type
> ```
>
> Even relatively straightforward compositions can rather quickly become
>   somewhat messy; deeper nesting is downright unwieldy:
>
> ```
> template< class T > using reference_t
>   = typename conditional<is_reference<T>::value, T,
>                          typename add_lvalue_reference<T>::type>::type;
> ```
>
> Worse, **accidentally omitting the keyword can lead to diagnostics
>   that are arcane to programmers** who are inexpert in metaprogramming
>   details.
>
> [...] We therefore **propose to add a set of template aliases** for the
>   library’s *TransformationTraits* **in order to reduce the programmer
>   burden** [...]. Note, in the following rewrite of the above example,
>   **the absence of any `typename` keyword**, as well as **the absence of any `::type` suffix**, thus **condensing the statement** from 3 to 2
>   lines of code:
>
> ```
> template< class T > using reference_t 
>   = conditional_t< is_reference<T>::value, T, add_lvalue_reference_t<T> >;
> ```
>
> [...] we recommend that aliases be **named according to a consistent
>   pattern**, namely **the name of the aliased trait suffixed by `_t`**,
>   the conventional suffix denoting a type alias. Thus, for example, the
>   alias for `add_cv<T>::type` would be `add_cv_t<T>`.

#### Favour using the alias templates for traits

Thus, generally, for brevity and a smaller risk for cryptic (lack of `typename`-induced) compiler errors, as of C++14 always favour using the alias template (e.g. `add_cv_t<T>`) over the more verbose form (e.g. `typename add_cv<T>::type`).

> [...] Are there any advantages or differences in using `std::enable_if_t`?

I.e., for your particular example, always favour using the alias template `std::enable_if_t<T>` over the more verbose form `typename enable_if<T>::type`.

---

## C++17 (P0006R0): Variable Templates for Traits

Note that as of C++17,

- [P0006R0: Adopt Type Traits Variable Templates from Library Fundamentals TS for C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html)

has been adapted which, in short applies a similar pattern for traits with a single, `static` member constant named `value`, supplying a variable template helper suffixed `_v`. Citing the summary/notes for P0006R0 from [P0636R0](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) (*Changes between C++14 and C++17 DIS*)

> For every standard type trait `foo` with a single, static member constant `foo<Args...>::value`, there is now a variable template `foo_v<Args...>`.

---

<sub>**(✝)** For some excellent talks from Walter E. Brown on templates, see e.g.:</sub>

- [CppCon 2018: Walter E. Brown “C++ Function Templates: How Do They Really Work?”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU),
- [CppCon 2014: Walter E. Brown "Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium, Part I"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY),
- [CppCon 2014: Walter E. Brown "Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium, Part II"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE).