# C++ template what does this class assignment in template mean?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, enable-if

```
template<classT>
class MyClass {
using KeyType = int;
using MapType = std::map<KeyType, int64_t>;
MapType map_;

template <class T1 = T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, int>{}>>
  IndexValueType LowerBound(KeyType k) const {
    auto it = map_.lower_bound(k);
    if (it == map_.end()) {
      return NOT_FOUND;
    }
    return it->second;
  }
};
```

What does these 2 assignments do in this context?

- `class T1 = T`
- `class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, int>{}>`

Comment: Ah I've edited the question. So in this case "T1 = T" just means T1 has the same class as T right? But then what's the point of this assignment?

Comment: From what you are showing it doesn't make much sense to me. There is probably more context missing. The template parameters make it so that `LowerBound` can only be called if `T` is `int` or `int` is given explicitly as template argument.

Comment: So using template<class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>{}>> should have the same effect (enable LowerBound if T is int) right?

Comment: No, `T1` is required to make SFINAE work. There is surely a duplicate for this somewhere if that is your question.

Comment: Ah okay so the keyword is SFINAE.

Comment: If your question is just what `enable_if` does, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284499/how-does-stdenable-if-work. For my previous comment see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function. Also for `enable_if_t` specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319649/what-is-the-difference-between-stdenable-if-and-stdenable-if-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LowerBound` is a [member template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template) function declared inside the [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) `MyClass`. It's similar to a function template but it is enclosed in a class (template).

The code can be simplified as

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {

    template <typename T1 = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, int>{}>>
    IndexValueType LowerBound(KeyType k) const {}
};
```

The first assignment `T1 = T` means the **default** argument for the first template parameter is the same type of `T`. If you are not explicitly specified, `T1` will be `T`. You could of course explicitly specify other types.

The second assignment here is an usage of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). Also pointed in the comments, it's a simple way to apply *SFINAE*. Here it will disable(ignore) templates when `T1` is not the same as `int`. Since the second parameter is only to restrict the first parameter and has no usage in the definition, its name is ignored.

```cpp
MyClass<int> mc1; // T is int
mc1.LowerBound(...) // T1 is int, when not specified explicitly
mc1.LowerBound<std::int32_t>(...) // T1 is std::int32_t here
MyClass<double> mc2; // T is double
mc2.LowerBound<int>(...) // OK, T1 is int 
mc2.LowerBound(...) // T1 is substitued with double here and will cause compile error since is not int
```